# Error converting a C ioctl/mmap call to Python?

Tags: python, c, embedded, cpython

I want to use a Linux driver with Python and I'm converting my C program.

My C program works fine but I have an error in Python: **IOError: [Errno 14] Bad address**

I'm using:

Python 2.7.13 (default, Jun 11 2018, 22:51:25) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux2

And my OS is Petalinux.

**This is the C program**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define DUMMY_IOC_MAGIC 'V'
#define DUMMY_START_TX_CYCLIC  _IO(DUMMY_IOC_MAGIC, 0)
#define DUMMY_START_TX  _IO(DUMMY_IOC_MAGIC, 1)

int main()
{
  int fd, j, ret;
  int32_t *map_vptr;
  size_t number_of_samples = 64;
  size_t size_sample = 4;
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  printf("Init tx.\n");
  fd = open("/dev/playback", O_RDWR | O_SYNC);
  if (fd < 0) {
    printf("Error opening device\n");
    return -1;
  }
  else{
    printf("Device is open...\n");
  }
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  map_vptr = (int32_t*) mmap(0, size_sample * number_of_samples, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
  if (map_vptr == MAP_FAILED) {
    close(fd);
    printf("Error mmapping the file\n");
    return -1;
  }
  printf("Mapped.\n");
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  int32_t *dst_ptr = map_vptr;
  int32_t counter = 0;
  for (j = 0; j < number_of_samples; ++j) {
    dst_ptr[j] = counter;
    counter = counter + 2;
  }
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // start TX transactions
  uint32_t tx_total_len = size_sample * number_of_samples;
  ret = ioctl(fd, DUMMY_START_TX, &tx_total_len);
  if (ret < 0)
  {
    printf("ioctl() failed, errno=%d\n", errno);
    return -1;
  }
  printf("End tx.\n");

  return 0;
}
```

**This is the Python program**

```py
import mmap, os, fcntl

#define DUMMY_START_TX _IO('V', 1)
DUMMY_IOC_MAGIC = 'V'
DUMMY_START_TX = ord(DUMMY_IOC_MAGIC) << (4*2) | 1

NUMBER_OF_SAMPLES = 64;
SIZE_SAMPLE = 4
################################################################################
# Open device
print("Init tx.");
fd = os.open("/dev/playback", os.O_RDWR | os.O_SYNC)
if (fd < 0):
    print("Error opening device")
    exit(-1);
else:
    print("Device is open...")
################################################################################
map_vptr = mmap.mmap(length = SIZE_SAMPLE*NUMBER_OF_SAMPLES, prot = mmap.PROT_READ | mmap.PROT_WRITE,
            flags = mmap.MAP_SHARED, fileno = fd, offset = 0)
print("Mapped.");
################################################################################
for i in range(0,NUMBER_OF_SAMPLES):
    map_vptr.write_byte(chr(i))
################################################################################
# start TX transactions
tx_total_len = SIZE_SAMPLE * NUMBER_OF_SAMPLES
ret = fcntl.ioctl(fd, DUMMY_START_TX, tx_total_len);

fd.close()

print("End tx.");
```

The output is:

```
Init tx.
Device is open...
Mapped.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tx_server.py", line 28, in <module>
    ret = fcntl.ioctl(fd, DUMMY_START_TX, tx_total_len);
IOError: [Errno 14] Bad address
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the Python doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fcntl.html#fcntl.fcntl):

> ```
> fcntl.fcntl(fd, op[, arg])
> ```
>
> The argument `arg` is optional, and defaults to the integer value `0`. When present, it can either be an integer value, or a string. With the argument missing or an integer value, the return value of this function is the integer return value of the C `fcntl()` call. **When the argument is a string it represents a binary structure, e.g. created by `struct.pack()`. The binary data is copied to a buffer whose address is passed to the C `fcntl()` call.** The return value after a successful call is the contents of the buffer, converted to a string object.

The above is also valid for `fcntl.ioctl()`. In your case instead of passing the integer directly you should use [`struct.pack()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.pack) to pass the value, like this:

```py
import struct

# ...

tx_total_len = SIZE_SAMPLE * NUMBER_OF_SAMPLES
ptr = struct.pack('I', tx_total_len)
#                  I == unsigned int of 4 bytes (uint32_t)

ret = fcntl.ioctl(fd, DUMMY_START_TX, ptr)
```

Comment: @CarlosAlbertoRuizNaranjo you're welcome. If this solved your problem you can accept my answer by clicking the checkmark button on the left, so that your question can be marked as solved.